# extract data from a file using bash

Tags: bash

I have the following text file -

```
1 A 1 
3 A 1
4 A 4
5 A 3
6 A 3
7 A 1
9 A 1
1 B 8
2 B 7
3 B 8
4 B 8
5 B 13
6 B 3
7 B 12
8 B 12
8 B 12
8 B 12
9 B 7
```

first column represents courses 1 to 9.
second column represents grades A and B.
third column represents no. of students which got the respective grade in respective course.
Now the output file should be like-

```
1 1 8 
2 0 7
3 1 8
4 4 8
5 3 13
6 3 3
7 1 12
8 0 12
9 1 7
```

first column represents course no. 
second column represents no. of students who got grade A in that course and third column represents no. of students who got B in that course.
Can someone tell me an easy way to do this using bash?

Comment: Why bash? Is this homework?

Comment: @Chrisji Yes, kind of. I know how to do this in perl.

Comment: @user314014 Show your code in Perl then. Also, this is [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). Are you sure that's the exact tool you want to use?

Comment: @konsolebox The second one for sure.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ((I=1;I<=9;I++)); do
  while read LINE; do 
    [[ "$LINE" =~ "$I A" ]] && A="$LINE"
    [[ "$LINE" =~ "$I B" ]] && B="$LINE"
  done < file.txt
  A="${A##* }"
  B="${B##* }"
  echo $I ${A:-0} ${B:-0}
  unset A B
done
```

Output:

```
1 1 8
2 0 7
3 1 8
4 4 8
5 3 13
6 3 3
7 1 12
8 0 12
9 1 7
```

Comment: +1 Neat but incomprehensible for a beginner. Could you please add a description of the overall idea?

Comment: Did you check the output? It prints `2 1 7` not `2 0 7`. Idea is good though. :) I guess A & B should be reset just after the echo statement otherwise it might not work.

Comment: @Technext: Thank you. The output was from an earlier version. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ewww, this is going to reread the file 9 times. Why don't you just use associative array?

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner should get you started:

```
join -2 <(grep A  data.txt) <(grep B data.txt) | tr -d AB
```

it works except for cases when no one got a A or no one got a B for one course.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A data
maxCourseId=0

while read -r course grade students; do
    ((maxCourseId = course > maxCourseId ? course : maxCourseId))
    ((data["$course $grade"] += students)) # or just = if you don't want numbers to add up
done < YOURFILE


for ((i = 1; i <= maxCourseId; i++)); do
    echo "$i ${data[$i A]:-0} ${data[$i B]:-0}"
done
```